# Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'l': expected 'r/R' or 'o/O' (line 1, column 20 (offset: 19))

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When I run following query in

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT Flight_flightId_constraint ON (f:Flight) ASSERT f.flightId IS UNIQUE
```

I get following error :

`Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'l': expected 'r/R' or 'o/O' (line 1, column 20 (offset: 19)) "CREATE CONSTRAINT Flight_flightId_constraint ON (f:Flight)"` ^

This is from https://guides.neo4j.com/4.0-neo4j-modeling-exercises/04.html exercise.

I do not understand why I get this syntax error becuase I ran the query as it is in tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using older version of Neo4j. The guide you are referring is for latest Neo4j version.
Constraint names are not supported in older versions hence it is throwing error.

**You can modify your query as bellow:**

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (f:Flight) ASSERT f.flightId IS UNIQUE
```